# How to sort Hudson builds by last run? (as opposed to last success or last failure)

Tags: hudson, regression, hudson-plugins, build-server

I'm trying to get more useful test results for our Hudson build, and I'd like to be able to sort all builds by `last run date`.

Unfortunately, It seems I can only sort by either `last success` or `last failure`.

Is there a way to add this functionality through the base app or via plugin?

Note that I already installed the extra columns plugin, but it doesn't seem to have this functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can view execution history on per-node bases, and that is reverse chronological order.

For the master, goto:
`http://<serverurl>/computer/(master)/builds`

You can also get there by click on your `master` node in executor's list and clicking **Build History**

There is also an RSS feed with the same information:
`http://<serverurl>/computer/(master)/rssAll`